# Why shoes in bed?

Tags: analysis, realism

It cringes me every time I see somebody more or less in their right mind in bed with shoes. How this become so common on TV (e.g. Buffy, Marvel Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D, whatever).

I understand that shooting socks may look lame and you need to allow some time to deboot between bursting in tears and splashing on bed, but **do you know of**  other reasons for TV guys to stay in bed with shoes?

One ideal answer would be: "In this interview producer Whois said she grew tired of looking dirty socks on screen so decided to just allow people with shoes in bed". Even better if producer Whois is able to share this experience directly here.

Alternatively, one may just say that laying in bed with shoes on is considered completely normal in US and everybody does it.

For examples: https://www.buzzfeed.com/crystalro/is-it-okay-to-wear-shoes-on-your-bed?utm_term=.wrmzl2Ex#.ymww7RM6

Comment: **In** bed, or **on** the bed?

Comment: My guess is too lazy to take them off after the 50th take.  Either that, or product placement.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an opinion based question, but as I see, it could be for few reasons, in those scenes, taking their shoes off would:

1. Look unnatural to many viewers. Many do not think anything about wearing shoes indoors, so seeing someone stopping to take them off would seem abnormal. Possibly trying to portray some situation as *normal*.
2. Require too many takes to get right. Mostly television series and/or low budget movies are on tight shooting schedules and on low amount of capital.  If too many takes were lost by an actor not being able to correctly remove their shoes, then series could go over time and budget.
3. Be largely meaningless - While a small number of viewers might be “happy” to see that American television now resembles their own lives, most Americans wouldn’t care one way or the other. Since the primary audience for American television is first and foremost Americans, our mores and cultural traits predominate.

Answer (score -1):

This is a not unnormal thing to do. Many people in real life will put their shoes on their bed, couch, table,  etc. Some people just don't have the same outlook as you.

Comment: "not unnormal" is a good way to put it. I myself think it is an awful thing to do that I also happen do do often enough. At least, my own stuff, not other peoples'

Comment: Great. Seems we are converging to a solution. I grew up with a strict "NO SHOES ON THE BED" policy. End everybody else around me. Maybe we are just living in a dirtier environment :)

Answer (score -1):

Often it's shown *because* it's lazy or unusual.

Looking at the examples in the buzzfeed link, the first guy immediately gives off a depressed, uncaring, "out of it" vibe by sitting upright and fully dressed in bed while staring off in to space. The 3rd example: fully clothed with scattered books on the bed and sleeping on top of the sheets makes it look like the character either passed out from exhaustion or just doesn't care about orderliness/cleanliness.

It's a quick way to add characterization or show mood.

Comment: And the second example (putting on shoes): I seldom, if ever actually put my shoes on the bed, but I do sit on the edge of the bed like that every morning to put my shoes on.  Not that weird.


And last example:  With all those laces, I'd probably leave those boots on for week at a time instead of going through all that work to take them off!  (who am I kidding; I'd never finish getting them on in the first place...)

Comment: Good point. But not sure. I seem to remember scene when character is just casually researching something on a computer or book (not sure where, almost sure - more than once). Or "just talking" scene. 
Also, I am asking this question to remove the guessing part. If somebody *knows* why (document, interview, personal experience) - please, share. Or maybe I am just too obsessed with all this shoes-on-bed story.